Boolean difference error in Geometry nodes
I'm trying to distribute geometry across a face to create a textured surface suitable for 3D printing.
I understand that Knife Project isn't available in geo nodes so I've tried boolean. I create instances and subtract them from the face and it gives inconsistent results (note the bottom left instance is correct but the others are not):

All of the instances are positioned correctly:


Any suggestions or alternative approaches?
Thanks

Make sure all your hulls are manifold and you have safety margins: e.g. don't cut out a hole from a 1 m cube, using exactly 1 m long (deep) cylinder. Also make sure your entire node tree is visible when you share it...

I added math nodes (not shown in the images) to eliminate all booleans at the edges, but that's not the issue. I wonder if boolean requires both operands to be manifold? The  first is a single face and isn't manifold. I intend to use this to to decorate faces on a much larger object.

I believe my thought about one operand being non manifold is the issue:  "Only Manifold meshes are guaranteed to give proper results,"
